# Show or hide query result depending on variable value in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-variable

I'm trying to show/hide queries on the graph panel **depending on the dashboard variable** values.

Motivation.

On the same graph panel (which is used to display several hosts) I have two queries:

```
rate(ClickHouseProfileEvents_Query{instance=~"$instance"}[$__rate_interval])
```

And:

```
max_over_time( (irate(ClickHouseProfileEvents_Query{instance=~"$instance"}[2m]))[$__rate_interval:15s] )
```

Where `ClickHouseProfileEvents_Query` is a counter.

The first one is a usual rate that is better for showing **trends**, and the other one is a little more complex but **shows all picks**. Of course, I would like to make one panel for the graph but also have some switches like trends/picks to analyze both. I've introduced a grafana dashboard variable with custom values, but I can't understand how I can use it to hide or show a particular query.

Also, I tried to make a single query using things like `or` or `unless` but unsuccessfully.

Environment: Grafana v7.5.2, Prometheus v2.26.0

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to [Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653675/marcelo-%C3%81vila-de-oliveira) for [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922697/13375075). My current solution is a little bit different but based on his idea.

First, I add type `Custom` variables with values `1` and `null.`

[image]

Second, I use multiply instead of division in my queries.

[image]

And finally, as a result, when I turn off, for example, trends showing, **I'm not seeing them both in graph and the legend too**.

[image]

Comment: Side note - the query for `picks` can be simplified to `rollup_rate(ClickHouseProfileEvents_Query{instance=~"$instance"})` when using MetricsQL. It returns `max`, `min` and `avg` rates by taking into account all the raw samples. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a custom variable with 2 values: 0 and 1

[image]

- Divide the query you want to control by the variable

[image]

- When "1" is selected all queries are showed

[image]

- When "0" is selected the query you've added the division is hided

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Marcelo's answer, instead of dividing by zero. There is a binary [operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) ***or*** and ***and*** in Prometheus, that will act like a disable/enable query button.

OR -> union

AND -> intersection

So, when we apply OR operator between a real query and some string it will query as it is while with AND operator it will take intersection with some string, which will result in no result.

Use Grafana Version 7.3.0 or above.

Define custom variable with ***or*** and ***and*** custom values.

***show : or*** represent the **label : value** for variable

[image]

Add $variable_name as suffix or prefix to the query along with one custom string.
[image]

When **show**, it will show the graph along with the legends.
In the below picture look for **sum** in the right table and the graph for sum legend query.
[image]

When **hide**, it will hide the graph and legend text completely.
In the below picture **sum** is hidden from the right table and the graph corresponding to it.
[image]

Comment: It works only for Prometheus and it does not work with Loki.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that you can even filter multiple queries with one variable, for example if you have 3 queries:

```
query1 * ($var % 2)
query2 * ($var % 3)
query3 * ($var % 5)

Value for $var ALL: 1
Value for $var only select query1 : 15
Value for $var only select query2 : 10
Value for $var only select query3 : 6
```

Works for infinite queries but the number gets bigger (for 4 queries with also % 7: 105 (2), 70 (3) , 126 (5) ,120 (7)) , but I think you shouldn't have much more than 4-5 queries in one dashboard anyway.

Residue field salvation ;-)